# ProgressDialog not stopping if I click twice on menu/button

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-progressbar

I am using `ProgressDialog` to show loading whenever user clicks on any menu, and it works fine. But when the user clicks twice on menus, `ProgressDialog` not stopping, it's running endlessly.

How can I solve this issue?

**This is my code structure:**

```
async void Grid_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    _pbr = Utilities.ProgressBar(this, "b").Show();
   switch (e.Position)
   {
    case 0:
        var result = await objHw.GetHomework(userid,log.LogInOrganizationID);
        if (resultA.Any())
        {
            //code
        }
        else
        {
            _pbr.Hide();
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Homework not available.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        _pbr.Hide();
        break;
    case 1: 
    case 2:
  }
}
```

**`Utilities.ProgressBar` method:**

```
public static ProgressDialog ProgressBar(Context context, string position)
{
    var pbr = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pbr.SetCancelable(false);
    pbr.Indeterminate = true;
    pbr.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
    switch (position.ToLower())
    {
        case "c":
            pbr.Window.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
            break;
        case "b":
            pbr.Window.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Bottom);
            break;
    }
    pbr.SetMessage("please wait..");
    return pbr;
}
```

**Loading...**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ProgressDialog not stopping if I click twice on menu/button

When user clicks twice on menus, avoid to create multiple instance for your `ProgressDialog` should resolve this issue:

```
public class Utilities
{
    public static ProgressDialog pbr;
    public static ProgressDialog ProgressBar(Context context, string position)
    {
        if(pbr == null)
        {
            pbr = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        pbr.SetCancelable(false);
        ...
        pbr.SetMessage("please wait..");
        return pbr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent yaar.